# Angular js 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After investigating in this error I found that it's coming from this piece of code, but I can't tell why and how to fix it.

```
$scope.mindate = function() {
    var thisDay = new Date();
    var priorDate = new Date().setDate(thisDay.getDate() - 90);
    return new Date(priorDate);
};
```

Comment: this error appears, when the digest cycle is run recursively, this generally happens when one change triggers the same change again and again. you will need to add more code and markup here to get to the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cache it:

```
$scope.mindate = function() {
    if(!$scope.mindateCached){
        var thisDay = new Date();
        var priorDate = new Date().setDate(thisDay.getDate() - 90);
        $scope.mindateCached = new Date(priorDate);
    }
    return $scope.mindateCached;   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular dirty check iteration is max 10. if your code has changed frequently before it finishes dirty check it will throw the error.
PS: Please post full code.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're always returning a "new Date()".

When you give a value to a model, angular will detect a change and trigger a digest cycle to apply all the changes. Once the first digest cycle is done it will go through everything again to check if anything has changed, if not it will stop and wait for the next change. If yes, it will go through another digest cycle.

In your case, because you're always returning a new Date() object angular will always detect something changed after every single cycle and there's a hard stop after 10 cycles after which angular will be like: "Ye, let's not run into an infinite loop." and you get the error you're getting now.

Comment: create a separate function that sets the $scope.mindate and only call that function when you want to change the mindate. If it's just to set the initial value, just call the function at the start of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

try to use bind-once inside html https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/